# Loading js file using Require JS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dependency-management

What is correct way to load modules through require js ?
I am new to Require js, and I am using it for loading different js modules required for my app. I am using Embedded JS ([EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/)) for template. Below is my code:

```
require.config({
                baseUrl: _URL+"/resources/",
                paths:
                {
                    moment: "js/moment.min",
                    ejs :  "js/ejs",
                    social_login : "public/social_login",
                    location : "js/location"
                },
                shim:
                {
                    ejs:
                    {
                        exports: 'ejs',
                        deps: ['moment']
                    },
                    social_login:
                    {
                         exports: 'social_login',
                         deps: ['moment','ejs']
                    },
                    location:
                    {
                         exports: 'location',
                         deps: ['moment','ejs','social_login']
                     }
                 },
                 waitSeconds: 20
            });
            require(["moment","ejs","social_login","location"],function()
            {
                callback("OK");
            });
```

Some time all modules load correctly and running, but when I repeatedly press **Ctrl + F5** or **F5** it gives me script error for ejs and other modules as in firebug console it gives:

[image]

I went through this link. [link1](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror) which says **there is a JavaScript syntax error or other execution problem running the script.**
What is the correct way to load ejs or any module ? I have downloaded latest version of it, is there any thing related with AMD module which EJS is not following ? I am quite blank, kindly help. Thanks

Comment: Where are the modules located ? I normally do it by placing them in a "modules" folder, below the folder where the main.js (or whatever you call it) is placed. Then I require the modules like this: "modules/mymodule"

Comment: @SteenT I kept them under `/resources/js/` path of my spring application. as you can see in above code. Is there any thing wrong with this ?

Comment: If the module/file required (social_login) is in the same location as the file you have shown the code from, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Load timeouts mean that the scripts didn't load. Check for 404s on the Network tab and look at the request paths if they are correct. Adjust your paths accordingly.

Also, don't use minified versions of libraries. This makes them hard to debug. RequireJS has its own optimizer which you can use when you push for production after development. It will compress all required files into one file.

In addition, you should use front-end package managers like [Bower](http://bower.io/). That way, you won't be copy-pasting libraries manually and prevent syntax errors caused by incorrect copy-paste. I personally use [Webapp Generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) to scaffold the app for me, so that I won't be copy-pasting libraries.

Comment: I change to non-minified version of ejs, but still the same script error while loading ejs.

Comment: @Aman `deps` is to be used when the current dependency requires that other library to load first, like how Bootstrap needs jQuery. AFAIK, ejs doesn't need momentjs to come before it. Don't think of loading the modules in order, Require does that for you

Comment: actually I need to do that, because previously loading moment js was another head ache, it was not getting initialized after loading through require js, hence I kept it on top, when moment js loads then other module will load. in that way. Thanks